# Центрирование блока внутри родителя

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с проблемой центрирования блока, при динамической ширине. 
Картинка как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не выходит центровать блок `.description` с `width:auto;` и `position:absolute;`, вот пример кода - http://jsfiddle.net/y2vqtzvg/

Comment: Текст в этом блоке известен или меняется? `position:absolute;` в совокупности с `top: 100px` поставит его по центру если текста будет две строки (как в фиддле) http://jsfiddle.net/y2vqtzvg/2/

Comment: @Cheslab, суть проблемы в том, чтобы выйти за рамки родительского блока и выйти так, чтобы родитель остался своего же размера

Comment: Тогда `width` пусть будет больше 100%, например 120%, и отрицательный `left` http://jsfiddle.net/y2vqtzvg/3/

Comment: может такой вариант подойдет - http://jsfiddle.net/suzhozLx/

Comment: @Cheslab в том-то и дело что ширина должна быть `auto` (

Comment: @soledar10, дело в том-то, что у блока должна быть ширина `auto` и он должен\может выходить за рамки родительского блока

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы внутренний блок имел `width: auto` и умел выходить за рамки родителя его нужно вынести из этого родителя в html, а затем снова центрировать.

```css
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center; 
}
.parent:before {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: '';
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
}
.description {
    width: auto;
    padding:10px 30px;
    background: #2fd72b;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
}
.myballoon {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-125px 0 0 -125px;
    min-height: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
    background: #5ea0e4;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.myballoon > .photo {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    display: block;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
}
.myballoon > .cycle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background: #2fd72b;
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    right: -25px;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="myballoon">
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <a href="#" class="cycle"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="description">много много много теста</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: если выносить блок за родителя, то все это свидется к одному дополнительному блоку, но необходимо оставаться в пределах `.myballoon` , так же он кликабелен и под ним еще есть активный слой.
вариант интересный, но проблему не решает(

Answer (score 0):

вот метод выровнять по центру вертикали:

```
.myballoon > .description {
    /* width: auto;  */
    padding: 0px;
    background: #2fd72b;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
   }
```

для чистоты эксперемента я сбросил значение padding до 0px

Comment: суть проблемы в том, чтобы выйти за рамки родительского блока и выйти так, чтобы родитель остался своего же размера)